# Pandas: Apply(): Return more than one value

Tags: python, pandas

My data is year-based, with year as an index. I have someFunc() that does some stuff on groupedBy data. However, it will return two values (two floats, not columns). I want to put these two values into two new columns in the old dataframe. Using a simple function for demonstration, what I had in mind was

```
def someFunc(group):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return pd.DataFrame([[a, b]], columns={'colA', 'colB'}, index=[group['year'][0]])
results = df.groupby(level=0).apply(someFunc)
pd.merge(df, results, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

However, this will create a double-indexed value: one because I added an index, and one index which comes from apply():

```
results
                colA        colB
year                            
1961 1961          1           2
1962 1962          1           2
1963 1963          1           2
```

and therefore, of course, the merge will not work. I have tried other various ways (including returning numpy arrays), but all of them are not neat. What should I do? I am aware that I could split the function up to run the code twice, once for each column - but that's not really efficient. To be clear, my expected results (for the variable result) is

```
results
                colA        colB
year                            
1961               1           2
1962               1           2
1963               1           2
```

And prior to this, data looks like

```
           c      a        b  
year                                                                          
1983     722   1001  1.06300  
1984     722   1001  1.24225   
1985     722   1001  2.78925   
1986     722   1001  0.59600   
1982  442110   1003  1.86300
```

**Intermediate Result**

```
return pd.DataFrame([[a, b]], columns=['colA', 'colB'], index=[group['year'].max()])
```

returns

```
           colA       colB
1961         30   2.434379
```

So then this is the key problem, right? It returns something with an index, and then `apply()` stacks its own index on top. Since there is no way to return a dataframe without index, I'd guess the solution must lie in affecting `apply()`

**Solution**

As posted in a comment somewhere down the road:

```
results = df.groupby(level=0).apply(someFunc).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Comment: Try `results = df.groupby(level=0).apply(someFunc, axis=1)`

Comment: someFunc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis' - or was I supposed to use that somehow in my function?

Comment: My mistake you can pass that param on a groupby apply, could you post some sample data so I can see what your df looks like prior to the groupby

Comment: I have added sample data.

Comment: I think I can get what you want but don't want to post my answer just yet try changing the last line in your someFunc to:`return pd.DataFrame([[a, b]], columns={'colA', 'colB'}, index=[group['year'].max()])`

Comment: Changing the index to `.max()` did not help (Why should it? `[0]` and `.max()` both return the same integer value). I updated with an intermediate result.

Comment: I've posted my code as an answer, but if it is different on yours then I'd need to see the full data and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me using your data

```
In [57]:

temp="""year           c      a        b                                                                
1983     722   1001  1.06300  
1984     722   1001  1.24225   
1985     722   1001  2.78925   
1986     722   1001  0.59600   
1982  442110   1003  1.86300 """

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='\s+')
df
Out[57]:
   year       c     a        b
0  1983     722  1001  1.06300
1  1984     722  1001  1.24225
2  1985     722  1001  2.78925
3  1986     722  1001  0.59600
4  1982  442110  1003  1.86300

[5 rows x 4 columns]
In [66]:

def someFunc(group):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    #print(group['year'].values)
    return pd.DataFrame([[a, b]], columns={'colA', 'colB'}, index=[group['year'].max()])
df.groupby(level=0).apply(someFunc)
Out[66]:
        colA  colB
0 1983     1     2
1 1984     1     2
2 1985     1     2
3 1986     1     2
4 1982     1     2

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

**EDIT**

After further discussion, the above code also shows the duplicated index you face so you can call `reset_index` to get rid of the duplication:

```
In [91]:

def someFunc(group):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return pd.DataFrame([[a, b]], columns={'colA', 'colB'}, index=[group['year'].max()])
df.groupby(level=0).apply(someFunc).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

Out[91]:
      colA  colB
1983     1     2
1984     1     2
1985     1     2
1986     1     2
1982     1     2

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Well your data does not have year as an index - that may be making the difference.

Comment: @FooBar So if you reset_index and then do groupby and apply does it work?

Comment: Oh wait. Yes, I can reproduce this when I reset the index. However, you also have a double index... I would like to have just the annual index, no other integers. My hackish way of doing this right now is adding `results = results.reset_index().drop('level_1', 1).set_index('year')` to my code

Comment: @FooBar, OK I see the problem, you could using your original code just drop the duplicate index values: `df.groupby(level=0).apply(someFunc).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)`